# Is CSRF mandatory for a backend REST application consuming JSON only?

Tags: spring, rest, security, csrf

Numerous resources claim that ([source1](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet)) ([source2](http://www.codesandnotes.be/2015/02/05/spring-securitys-csrf-protection-for-rest-services-the-client-side-and-the-server-side/))

> For resources exposed by RESTful web services, it's important to make sure **any PUT, POST, and DELETE request is protected from Cross Site Request Forgery**.
>
> **CSRF is mandatory for all applications** with a minimum of concern about web security

However [the Spring Security docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html) say:

> use CSRF protection for any request that could be processed by a browser by normal users. If you are only creating a **service that is used by non-browser clients**, you will likely want to **disable CSRF protection**.

So, is it ok to disable CSRF for an application that?

- only exposes a REST API
- only consumes JSON (checks the requests Content-Type header)

Comment: well, what's the application do? if the json it accepts is something like `{"command":"nuke the universe"}`, you may want to have a WEE BIT of protection on it to make sure that the snotnosed little scriptkiddy next door can't issue that command...

Comment: The fact that it doesn't serve HTML and only consumes JSON is not what matters. What matters is: are requests targeting the REST service supposed to come from browser clients or not.

Comment: @JBNizet They come from Javascript running in browsers, but not from submitting HTML forms as it is impossible to submit a form with content type application/json.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the client of your API. CSRF attacks are based on the fact that client automatically sends cookies (authorization) of requested URL with the HTTP request. If your client is not doing that (typically browsers do that automatically), you should be OK.

The reason why is: If your API consumer is not authenticated/authorized in your application via cookies (that are automatically stored by the browser), attacker cannot use any other web page to do successful CSRF attack (send HTTP request from other page with cookies of your API from browser).

In other words, I can't imagine that you will have API client written in a way that it can send requests to your API, store cookies (your authentication) and also can somehow show you some content that "silly" user interacts - sends requests to your API with cookies (your authentication) from previous API requests.

Comment: Well... it does matter when it comes to exploiting. The only way to send an application/json request in a browser is using Javascript, but then the Same Origin Policy prevents JS from making a request to a host of a different origin and switches to use CORS, CORS issues a preflight request to my REST and then my REST can reject it.

Comment: You mean content type? Well partially but generally I don't see how you can make successful CSRF attack without client that acts like browser - in other words that stores cookies (that authorize you) and can make requests to your API and also to any malicious web page (that re-takes cookies of API requests)

Comment: Cookies do not have to be involed in CSRF attacks. I am logged in mybank.com using HTTP Basic auth (let's assume), I enter evil.com where there is <form action="http://mybank.com/withdraw"> and I click Submit on evil.com it is still a CSRF attack despite no cookies were involved.

Comment: I wrote cookies (your authentication), HTTP basic is special case of headers that work the similar way as cookies in the browser (it gets added to HTTP request automatically by browser)... Read "In other words" part...

Comment: I have never mentioned that I use cookies for authentication. Yes, HTTP basic auth is added as a header, but it is a completely different thing than a cookie... c'mon. Ok, not HTTP basic auth, HTTP digest, yes, also passed as a header, but its handling is more complex and just storing and passing values like in case of cookies, right?

Comment: You are right. I know you are not using cookies, probably basic auth. What I wanted to point out is that CSRF is "client-side" attack. If your API client does not expose your "credentials" (cookie, basic auth, bearer token), you should be fine. What CSRF uses is fact that browser automatically sends them no matter what web page requests them (if used in <img> tag for example).

Comment: Ok, and now back to my previous point... "browser automatically sends them no matter what web page requests" no, browsers **do not send at all** application/json requests from web pages (that is why Content-type matters) they only send application/json requests from Javascript and if they are to send such a request to a host of a different origin they use CORS.

Comment: Ok, I get you know, my bad with the content-type - updated answer. Actually I'm not sure if you can somehow bypass content-type by using proper elements/form actions. Anyway it does not change the answer. If you are not using browser clients (or clients that act like them), I don't see how you can be attacked by CSRF

Comment: "I don't see how you can be attacked by CSRF" I fully agree with that :) thank you for the interesting discussion :)

Comment: My pleasure, it helped me to realize that content-type may matter. I will investigate further whether there is a way how to bypass this header from form/element :-) I recommend you to wait for few other answers (if there are any) to verify.

Comment: seems like no-one other will answer... If you still agree with my answer, please mark it as correct one so the question does not remain opened forever. Thanks:-)

Comment: Yes however what is important  if your API endpoint is relying on a cookie /or some mechanism to reestablish the session. If you are not using cookie and using some auth token that cannot be constructed easily by clients or cannot be sent by browser automatically then csrf  is not needed. Because there is no mechanism to identify old session with pure stateless rest APIs , csrf can be disabled in this case

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy to explain this:

A CSRF token is generated based on `Http Session`. If your API is holding the http session, you properly wanna to secure it with CSRF token, *BUT* most REST services are designed to be stateless, in that case you cannot/shouldn't/wouldn't use a CSRF token.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct. How you want to attack HTTP-session like API (e.g. with bearer token) without browser (or client that automatically sends cookies)?

Comment: `BUT most REST services are designed to be stateless` that is not true, most of the time we need http sessions to determine which user is making the request and if your service is vulnerable to CSRF, attackers can make requests instead of the real user (usually happens in browser side)

Comment: Rest APIs are supposed to be stateless and every request sends session identifying encrypted jwt token to reestablish it.in this case csrf is not needed as there is no way for attacker to take advantage of user agent that automatically sends session identifying info. If your rest APIs set any kind of cookie related to session which can help application to associate it with a session then you need csrf as browsers will send cookies automatically.